# Capturing after the nth occurrence of a string using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

My test string:

```
/custom-heads/food-drinks/51374-easter-bunny-cake
```

I am trying to capture the number in the string. The constants in that string are the the number is always preceded by 3 `/`'s and followed by a `-`.

I am a regex noob and am struggling with this. I cobbled together `(\/)(.*?)(-)` and then figured I could get the last one programmatically, but I would really like to understand regex better and would love if someone could show me the regex to get the last occurrence of numbers between `/` and `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regexes if possible, i reccomend you to read - https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ blog post

To your question, its easier, faster, more bullet proof to get it using splits

```js
const articleName = "/custom-heads/food-drinks/51374-easter-bunny-cake".split("/")[3]
// '51374-easter-bunny-cake'

const articleId = articleName.split("-")[0]

// '51374'
```

hope it helps

Comment: 2 operations: `.split("/")[3]` followed by `.split("-")[0]` is equivalent of `/^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}([^-]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex with a capture group:

```sh
^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}([^-]+)
```

Or in modern browsers you can use lookbehind assertion:

```
/(?<=^(?:[^\/]*\/){3})[^-]+/
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/UYHGx1/1)

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/UYHGx1/1)

**RegEx Code:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:[^\/]*\/){3}`: Match 0 or more non-`/` characters followed by a `/`. Repeat this group 3 times
- `([^-]+)`: Match 1+ of non-hyphen characters

**Code:**

```js
const s = `/custom-heads/food-drinks/51374-easter-bunny-cake`;

const re = /^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}([^-]+)/;

console.log (s.match(re)[1]);
```

Comment: This is _really_ close. Only issue is that it matches all the text before the number as well as the number. How do I omit that first group from the match?

Comment: That's why we use capture group for number. Modern Javascript uses lookbehind so you can use: `/(?<=^(?:[^\/]*\/){3})[^-]+/`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const str = `/custom-heads/food-drinks/51374-easter-bunny-cake`
const p = /(?:\/[^\/]*){2}\/(\d+)-/
console.log(str.match(p)?.[1])
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fOsp7S/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```
Non-capturing group (?:\/[^\/]*){2}
{2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
\/ matches the character / with index 4710 (2F16 or 578) literally (case sensitive)
  Match a single character not present in the list below [^\/]
  * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  \/ matches the character / with index 4710 (2F16 or 578) literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / with index 4710 (2F16 or 578) literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (\d+)
  \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
  + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- matches the character - with index 4510 (2D16 or 558) literally (case sensitive)
```